Compound word challenge: Dying while taking a selfie
German, of course, is known for having many wonderful multi-syllabic compound words for which there is no English equivalent (e.g., Verschlimmbesserung). Can someone invent one for the recent phenomenon of "dying while taking a selfie"?

I suggest Videozid.

Selfizid
Wie wär's damit?
Das war die Antwort, aber das System benörgelt gerne Antworten als zu kurz, daher hier noch die Synthese, die aber wohl alle erkennen, als Verschmelzung von Selfie, dem üblichen dt. Terminus, mit Suizid.

Das klingt nach einem absichtlichen Ableben, ich vermute aber, typischer ist das rücklings von der Klippe Herunterfallen und ähnliche Unglücke. Die sind dann auch kein Suizid. Aber sehr guter Versuch!

@Alazon: in dem Falle würde ich "Geschiehtdirrecht" vorschlagen.

Die Nachsilbe -zid benennt in der Regel eine absichtliche Tötung des im ersten Wortteil benannten Lebewesens: beim Regizid des Königs, beim Patrizid des Vaters und im Falle des Sui-zids eben des Täters selbst. Selfizid wäre somit die Tötung eines Selfies und würde dessen vorherige Lebendigkeit voraussetzen.

@TilmanSchmidt: Herbizid, Funghizid und Pestizid bezeichnen m.W. vornehmlich Substanzen, die zur Tötung verwendet werden. Wiktionary nennt https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/-zid Töten und Morden, d.h. der absichtslose Effekt ist nicht ausgenommen, selbst ein bewusstes Inkaufnehmen der Gefahr, welches vielleicht nicht immer vorliegt, ist nicht nötig. Im Alltagssprachgebrauch wird sehr riskantes Verhalten gelegentlich mit "Suizid" kurzgeschlossen, "Eine solche Entscheidung wäre Selbstmord!", riskanter Fahrstil eines Motorradfahrers wird mit "Selbstmörder" o. "Organspender" kommentiert. (...)

(...) Sicher würde ich "Selfiezid" nicht in jeder Sprachsituation benutzen. Im Internet/Influencer/Meme-Umfeld, aus dem wir auch den Darwinaward kennen, scheint es mir geeignet. Die Bildersuche spuckte mir jedenfalls v.a. Bilder aus, die Situationen zeigen, bei denen der, der die Bilder schoss, wohl auf den Thrill des Risikos mit abzielte - wieso sonst legt man sich auf Schienen, balanciert am Rand eines Felsüberhangs, springt aus dem Hubschrauber? Schwer vorhersehbare Unfallgefahren dürften selten gemeint, wenn auch nicht ausgeschlossen sein. Beim Googeln fand ich jetzt auch "Selficide".

Aus Selfie und eliminieren: selfilimiert
Passt besser zu dem passiven Charakter als Suizid.

Blend words have the disadvantage that they will need to be explained, or will generally have to be put into quotes on first usage. Inspired by @guidot, I suggest
Selfie-Unfalltod
as a mostly self-explaining word, albeit somewhat long. Unfalltod (accidental death) is an established compound, and the role a selfie would have on the Unfalltod seems clear to me, too. The people killed would be Selfie-Unfalltote.
But looking at newspapers, they mostly use tödliche Selfie-Unfälle (deadly selfie accidents) DiePresse.com titles with the blend word Selfiecide, but talks about tödliche Selfie-Unfälle in-text. handelsblatt.de writes about Selfie-Tode (selfie deaths) and Selfie-Todesfälle (selfie fatalities). Another interesting word I found in travelbook.de is Selfie-Todesursachen (selfie death causes).

ITod/IDeath
A possible problem with this is perhaps that corpses produced by ITod only fit in coffins from Apple and if the victim hasn't valid subscriptions to both IHell and IHeaven the phone won't let him die properly until he does so.

Another problem is what to do if the self-elliminating selfieist was using an Android phone.

I don't consider a -zid composition, since the first part in existing compositions always seems to describe, what is killed, so Fungizid is something killing fungi, Suizid is killing oneself, Genozid ... etc.
My proposal is

Selfie-Jagdunfall

(The hyphen here separates Denglish and German language components, and might also be dropped.)
While this neither conveys, that the hunter is also the victim, nor that the accident is lethal, I see no way to add one of those aspects without arriving at a word-monster nobody would like to use. (The latter can be expressed by tödlicher Selfie-Jagdunfall).

Da es keine Regel gibt, die einen Bindestrich zum Fremdwortanteilen eines Wortes nahelegen, würde ich doch, wenn schon, eher Selfiejagd-Unfall empfehlen. Schließlich ist es ein Unfall auf Selfiejagd, nicht ein Selfie beim Jagdunfall (außer in Ausnahmefällen).

That event would be a Smartphoneselbstschnappschussstolpersterbefall (smartphone self snapshot stumble death), which would of course be quite a Smartphoneselbstschnappschussstolpersterbeschicksalsschlag (smartphone self snapshot stumble stroke of fate).
Engage Bodo Wartke as the Smartphoneselbstschnappschussstolpersterbeschicksalsschlagsseelenamtsänger (smartphone self snapshot stumble stroke of fate requiem singer).

Bodo to the rescue! Thanks, that really made me laugh. Not +1 as it tends not to roll off the tongue in everyday life though

Brilliant! Not being a German speaker myself, I didn't get all of it. Could you break it down for us simpletons?  Many thanks!

@Wm.Alexander no problem, edited

@HalvarF Grazie mille!

Selfschnapptod. Mixes "Schnappschuss" (snap shot) and "selfie" and "schnapp" (sudden grasp).
